# float:left display border but not center of the page?

Tags: html, css

check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H5862/)

i have a `<div class"main">` it's css when i use this

```
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    float:left;
}
```

it display border but goes left not center

```
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
```

and when i remove float:left it goes at center but doesn't show border.

so what can i use to make page at center with showing border?

Thanks

Comment: Have you cleared the float(s) properly?

Comment: yes i tried but still not working. THnks

Comment: @jaiff did you check my answer?

Comment: you can use overflow:hidden and remove float from #main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.main`, there have floated elements which needs to be clear. You can clear them using  `clearfix`

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after{
    clear: both;
}
```

Add `clearfix` class to `main` div like

```
<div class"main clearfix">...</div>
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/H5862/8/)

Answer (score 0):

When you add floating element you need to clear the elements using `clear:both` css property. Add the following code in your HTML before closing the main div.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H5862/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using percentages, http://jsfiddle.net/H5862/3/

```
.main
{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 100%;
   border:2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: width should be 1000px

Comment: works with fixed width, pls see http://jsfiddle.net/H5862/5/ ,was just showing how you could use percentages to scale automatically if you wanted to.

Comment: but how it scale automatically using percentage i want it to align at page center